# Is the helicity of photon Lorentz invariant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, photons, reference-frames, helicity

If the helicity of a photon is $+1$ in an inertial frame, then is
the helicity of this photon $+1$ in another inertial frame? The helicity
operator is

$$
h=\mathbf{S}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{p}}
$$

with
$$
S_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -i\\
0 & 0 & i & 0
\end{array}\right),\ S_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & i\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -i & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),\ S_{3}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -i & 0\\
0 & i & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$